# Right click set rule context menu in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, context-menu, email-filter, thunderbird-addon

I can't seem to find an add-on or setting for this and it's not provided by default like it is in Outlook 2010.

Is there any way I can get this functionality? It's extremely useful as I create a lot of rules to filter incoming emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly the answer I was looking for but an answer nonetheless. If you left click on the `Senders` address in an open email you can click `Create Filter From...` which pulls the address into a basic filter creation panel. You can then set it to be moved to a folder and save it. I doubt it could be made much faster/easier.